# UseParams() not working and not rendering data on screen

Tags: reactjs, react-router-dom

I am working on an eCommerce website and I am stuck .
I am mapping through a array and it renders Image and a link . I want to click the link(checkitem)  on image and it should open the Image and detail in different page but its not working.
I am using reactrouter for it and passing the id of the image to useparams() in my Fullcard component . In my Full  card component i am filtering and mapping the array according to the id of the image , but it seems to not work .Can you guys help me.

Here is the CodeSandboxLink of the project : https://codesandbox.io/s/strange-driscoll-gpl629?file=/src/App.js

Here is my Appjs :

```
import Hero from './Hero';
import { BrowserRouter as Router, Route, Routes } from "react-router-dom";
import FullCard from "./FullCard";
function App() {

  const data = [
    {
      burh: "1fdsd",
      id: 1,
      img: "https://d3o2e4jr3mxnm3.cloudfront.net/Mens-Jake-Guitar-Vintage-Crusher-Tee_68382_1_lg.png",
    },
    {
      burh: "1fdsd",
      id: 2,
      img: "https://cdn.shopify.com/s/files/1/0101/4832/products/Angela_Natural_Tee.png?v=1606780388",
    },
    {
      burh: "1fdsd",
      id: 3,
      img: "https://www.prada.com/content/dam/pradanux_products/U/UCS/UCS319/1YOTF010O/UCS319_1YOT_F010O_S_182_SLF.png",
    },
    {
      burh: "1fdsd",
      id: 4,
      img: "https://www.burdastyle.com/pub/media/catalog/product/cache/7bd3727382ce0a860b68816435d76e26/107/BUS-PAT-BURTE-1320516/1170x1470_BS_2016_05_132_front.png",
    },
  ];




  return (
    <Router>
      <Routes>
        <Route path="/" element={<Hero data={data}/>} />
        <Route path="/products/:id" element={ <FullCard data={data} />} />
      </Routes>
    </Router>
  );
}

export default App;
```

Here is my Card:

```
// import { popularProducts } from "./data";
import { Link } from "react-router-dom";
import "./Card.css";

const Card = ({ data }) => {
  return (
    <div className="Maincontainer">
      <div className="CardContainer">
        {data.map((items, index) => {
          return (
            <div className="cards" key={index}>
              <img src={items.img} alt="/" />

              <Link to={`/products/${items.id}`}>CheckItem</Link>
            </div>
          );
        })}
      </div>
    </div>
  );
};

export default Card;
```

Here is my Full card comp:

```
import { useParams  } from 'react-router-dom'

const FullCard = ({data}) => {

    const {id} = useParams();


  return (
    <div className='container'>
        {data.filter(  (items )=> items.id === id ).map((items,index) =>{
            return (
                <div key={items} className="container2">
                    <h1>{items.burh}</h1>
                    {/* <img src={items.image} alt="/" /> */}
                </div>
            );
        })}
    </div>
  )
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

## Issue

The `id` properties in `data` are number types, but the `id` route match param will be a string. The data filtering in `FullCard` is failing because you are using strict equality, which requires both operands to be of the same type. In this case, either both numbers or both strings.

```
{data
  .filter((items) => items.id === id) // <-- type mismatch comparision
  .map((items, index) => {
    return (
      <div key={items.id} className="container2">
        <h1>{items.burh}</h1>
        {/* <img src={items.image} alt="/" /> */}
      </div>
    );
  })}
```

## Solution

Either use loose equality, i.e. `==` so type coercion/conversion is attempted in determining equality

```
.filter((items) => items.id == id)
```

or convert the `items.id` to a string and use string equality

```
.filter((items) => String(items.id) === id)
```

[image: Edit useparams-not-working-and-not-rendering-data-on-screen]

Comment: @ShazzyFazzy No worries. We've all put on the code blinders at one point or another in our lives. Cheers and good luck!

Answer (score 1):

`useParams()` is working fine. As `id` in FullCard is of type string so you are comparing type and value both in FullCard filter.
So please use `items.id==id` or `items.id===Number(id)`.